# Sending messages > ~3.5MB for AMQP CPP blocks for >30s

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, amqp

When publishing messages which are larger than ~3.5MB (amqp.publish()), they only appear in the RabbitMQ library after a "big" delay. (>30s).

If the package is smaller, the message basically arrives instantly (<100ms).

I couldn't find any way to configure amqp-cpp.

Comment: What is "the RabbitMQ library"? Really, the only way someone will be able to assist you is if you provide the code you are using to publish and consume messages in a form that they can compile and run it. Anything else and you're asking people to take their valuable time and try to guess how to reproduce your issue.